# 'Undefined' when trying to access json response

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

My flask app has code that returns the following:

```
return json.dumps({'status': 'OK','url': 'www.blahg.com'})
```

My javascript code looks like this:

```
$(function() {
  $('#mainbutton').click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/buttonclick',
            data: $('form').serialize(),
            type: 'POST',
            success: function(response) {
                console.log(response);
                console.log(response.url);
            },
            error: function(error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

The first console log looks correct: `{"status": "OK", "url": "www.blahrg.com"}`, but when I try to access the `url` entry, I get 'undefined' as output. what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure it is not a string `'{"status": "OK", "url": "www.blahrg.com"}'`? Try `var response = JSON.parse(response);`

Comment: Is it possible that `response` is a JSON string? Try using `JSON.parse` first

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can also use `dataType` to have jQuery parse it for you:

```
$(function() {
  $('#mainbutton').click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/buttonclick',
            data: $('form').serialize(),
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json', // this bit here
            success: function(response) {
                console.log(response);
                console.log(response.url);
            },
            error: function(error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 7):

You haven't parsed the JSON:

```
success: function(data) {
    var response = JSON.parse(data);
    console.log(response);
    console.log(response.url);
}
```